# Transforming a dataset from SQL to RDD[vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I know several questions has been asked on similar topics but I couldn't apply any of the answers to my problem, also I am wondering about best practices.

I have loaded a dateset for ML to a SQL database. I want to apply mllib's clustering function according to it. I have loaded the SQL database to `DataFrame` using `sqlContext`, dropped the irrelevant columns. then happened the problematic part, I create a vector by parsing each row of the DataFrame. 
The Vector is then transformed to RDD using the `toJavaRDD` function.

Here is the code (works):

```
val usersDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost/database").
  option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","table").
  option("user","woot").option("password","woot-password").load()

val cleanDF = usersDF.drop("id").drop("username")
cleanDF.show()

val parsedData = cleanDF.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").trim.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()

val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.6,0.4), seed = 11L)
val train_set = splits(0).cache()

val gmm = new GaussianMixture().setK(2).run(train_set)
```

My main question regards to what I read on spark documentation about: [Local vector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html), in my understanding the DataFrame mapping will be performed on the workers and later will be sent to the Driver when creating the Vector(Is that the meaning of local vector) only to later be sent to the workers again? isn't there a better way to achieve this?

Another things is that it seems a little odd to load SQL to DataFrame only to turn it into string and parse it again. Are there any other best practices suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html) you suggested

> A local vector has integer-typed and 0-based indices and double-typed
>   values, stored on a single machine. MLlib supports two types of local
>   vectors: dense and sparse.
>
> A distributed matrix has long-typed row and column indices and
>   double-typed values, stored distributively in one or more RDDs.

The local vector are behaving like any object you would use for your RDD (String, Integer, Array), they are created and stored *on a single machine*, the worker node, and only if you collect them they will be sent to the driver node.

If you consider a vector `x` of size `2n` storing it distributively you would separate it in two halfs of length `n`, `x1` and `x2`, `(x = x1::x2)`. To perform the dot product with another vector `y`, the workers will perform `r1=x1*y1` (on machine 1) and `r2=x2*y2` (on machine 2) and then you will need to group the partial results giving `r=r1+r2`. Your vector `x` is distributed, the vectors `x1` and `x2` are again local vectors. If you have `x` as a local vector then in a single step you can perform on a worker node `r=x*y`.

For your second question, I do not see why you would store the vectors in SQL format. Having a CSV file like this would be sufficient:

```
label feature1 feature2 ...
1,    0.5,     1.2      ...
0,    0.2,     0.5      ...
```